# Redactor default .json

Tags: redactor

From what I understand, the "Default" .json-file is hardcoded into the plugin, and always selected by default when creating a redactor field. I always use my "Standard.json" or "Simple.json"-files on my projects, the Default config has way too many options for less design savy clients to mess things up, so I try to keep things simple. Is there any way to make my "Standard.json" selected when creating a new field so I don't have to remember to change the .json-source every time?

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file to the default.